# ReferenceArrayInput usage with relationships on React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I have followed the doc for the ReferenceArrayInput (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props) but it does not seem to be working with relationship fields.

For example, I have this many-to-many relation for my Users (serialized version) :

[image]

Coming from (raw response from my API):

[image]

I have setup the ReferenceArrayInput as followed :

```
 <ReferenceArrayInput source="profiles" reference="profiles" >
           <SelectArrayInput optionText="label"  />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

I think it's making the appropriate calls :

[image]

But here is my result :

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On docs, ReferenceArrayInput is said to expect a source prop pointing to an array os ids, array of primitive types, and not array of objects with id. Looks like you are already transforming your raw response from api, so if you could transform a bit more, mapping [{id}] to [id], it could work.
If other parts of your app expects profiles to be an array of objects, just create a new object entry like profilesIds or _profiles.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I found the solution this morning, I have to format my response on the ReferenceArrayInput and then I transform it back on serialization before sending the data to my api.

Answer (score 0):

As gstvg said, `ReferenceArrayInput` expects an array of primitive type, not array of objects.

If your current record is like below:

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [
        { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
        { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' }
     ]
}
```

And you have a resource `/tags`, which returns all tags like:

```js
[
    { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' }
]
```

Then you can do something like this (it will select the tags of current record)

```js
<ReferenceArrayInput
      reference="tags"
      source="tags"
      parse={(value) => value && value.map((v) => ({ id: v }))}
      format={(value) => value && value.map((v) => v.id)}
    >
      <AutocompleteArrayInput />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```